# Changing photograph on Facebook "like" link to web site

Tags: facebook, photos, facebook-like

I just added a LIKE button to one of my web sites and Liked it myself. When I go to my timeline, a very nice photo from my site shows up. Added it to a second site and Liked it. When I go to my timeline the photo that comes up was one that said Happy New Year and all that shows up is HA. It looks retarded. I have deleted it from my timeline, taken it off my site, closed everything down and it still comes up. I even tried taking Happy New Year off my site and out of photo shop. I go back and start completely from scratch and the same stupid looking photo keeps coming up. I want it to look professional and HA doesn't cut it.

How can I change the photograph?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like your photo from your website was cached, you may want to

- Re-like the page
- Place the link in the linter https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

> Facebook scrapes your page every 24 hours to ensure the properties are up to date. The page is also scraped when an admin for the Open Graph page clicks the Like button and when the URL is entered into the Facebook URL Linter. Facebook observes cache headers on your URLs - it will look at "Expires" and "Cache-Control" in order of preference. However, even if you specify a longer time, Facebook will scrape your page every 24 hours.